Android studio 2024.2.1 flutter build error app_plugin_loader.groovy Unsupported class file major version 65
Upgraded to Android studio Android studio 2024.2.1. Even did a fresh install.
Made a new Flutter project. When I run it, I get this error.
Launching lib\main.dart on Pixel 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit 'C:\Users\Rok\Flutter SDK\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\app_plugin_loader.groovy' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s

┌─ Flutter Fix ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [!] Your project's Gradle version is incompatible with the Java version that Flutter is using   │
│ for Gradle.                                                                                     │
│                                                                                                 │
│ If you recently upgraded Android Studio, consult the migration guide at                         │
│ https://flutter.dev/to/to/java-gradle-incompatibility.                                          │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Otherwise, to fix this issue, first, check the Java version used by Flutter by running `flutter │
│ doctor --verbose`.                                                                              │
│                                                                                                 │
│ Then, update the Gradle version specified in                                                    │
│ C:\Users\Rok\FlutterProjects\Test\test20241009\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties │
│ to be compatible with that Java version. See the link below for more information on compatible  │
│ Java/Gradle versions:                                                                           │
│ https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java                               │
│                                                                                                 │
│                                                                                                 │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Can run Android Java project without problems.
Tried a full uninstall and reinstall of Android Studio.

The same happened to me today, after installing Android Studio Ladybug 2024.2.1.
As far as I understand, this is related to the new Java 21 version installed by AS.
c:\android-studio\jbr\bin\java.exe --version
openjdk 21.0.3 2024-04-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11, mixed mode)

Solution

Update gradle-wrapper.properties

C:\project_path\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.9-all.zip


Update android/build.gradle to gradle:8.7.0

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        THIS ->
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.7.0'
    }
}


Update settings.gradle to gradle:8.7.0

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    
    THIS ->
    id "com.android.application" version "8.7.0" apply false
    
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.1" apply false
    id "com.google.firebase.crashlytics" version "3.0.0" apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf' version '1.4.2' apply false
    id "com.huawei.agconnect" version "1.9.1.303" apply false
}


Update NDK in Android Studio if you get a build error like below

A problem occurred configuring project ':fvp'.
> com.android.builder.sdk.InstallFailedException: Failed to install the following SDK components:
      ndk;27.0.12077973 NDK (Side by side) 27.0.12077973
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.


Manually enter the new NDK (if required)

android {
    namespace 'my app.com'
    
    compileSdkVersion 34
                        
    ndkVersion "28.0.12433566"
...


Update libs (if required) ->

pubspec.yaml
audio_session: ^0.1.21
chewie: ^1.8.5
video_player: ^2.9.2
just_audio: ^0.9.41
just_audio_background: ^0.0.1-beta.13

Execution failed for task ':audio_session:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Manually modify video_player_android (if required)

c:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\video_player_android-2.4.12\android\build.gradle 

see below link
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/148478#issuecomment-2358072537

THIS -> def args = ["-Xlint:deprecation","-Xlint:unchecked"]
instead do def args = ["-Xlint:deprecation","-Xlint:unchecked","-Werror"]

THIS -> warningsAsErrors false
instead of warningsAsErrors true

Warnung: [options] Verwenden Sie -Xlint:-options, um Warnungen zu veralteten Optionen zu unterdrücken.
Fehler: Warnungen gefunden und -Werror angegeben
1 Fehler
3 Warnungen

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':video_player_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Build project

flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

First build time may take longer (about 30 minutes for my project), so be patient.

Sometimes you may need to manually delete old packages from cache c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\

You are done! Easy peasy!



Updated gradle-wrapper.properties to
` distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip
and int settings.gradle to:
` id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
Did flutter clean, pub get and the run worked.
Would upvote your answer, but I don't have 15 reputation. Tnx!

I am on the verge of completely deleting and abandoning android studio because of these stupid problems

yeah, it's pretty annoying when updating an IDE we need to update the project

This error occurs due to an incompatibility between the version of Java you're using and the Gradle version specified in your Flutter project.
Solution:
Check the Java version Flutter is using
Run the following command to verify the Java version being used by Flutter:
flutter doctor --verbose

Look for the Java version in the output.
Update the Gradle version
Based on the Java version from the previous step, you need to update your gradle-wrapper.properties file. This file is located at:
<your-project>/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Modify the distributionUrl to a compatible Gradle version. For example:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-<compatible-version>-all.zip

Replace  with the correct version based on your Java version. You can refer to the compatibility table here.
Sync and rebuild the project
Once you've updated the Gradle version, sync your project in Android Studio to apply the changes. Then, run the following commands to clean and rebuild the project:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run

These steps should resolve the issue.
Additional Resources:

Gradle and Java compatibility
Flutter migration guide for Java and
Gradle issues

